# Does this VBA code side-effect on Visio's recalculation queue also happen in .NET VSTO solutions?

Tags: .net, vb.net, vsto, office-interop, visio

To optimize the performance of Visio code that changes a Visio diagram and formulas in cells of Visio shapes, Visio has the Application.DeferRecalc property to prevent continuous recalculation of the internal Visio model to optimize performance.

Microsoft even states:

> Ideally, you should only set formulas when recalculation is turned
> off.

See article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.application.deferrecalc).

Microsoft however provides a code example in VBA:

```
Dim blsDeferCalcOriginalValue As Boolean 
blsDeferCalcOriginalValue = Application.DeferRecalc 
Application.DeferRecalc = True 
vsoShape.Cells("height").ResultIU = 12 
vsoShape.Cells("width").ResultIU = 14 
Application.DeferRecalc = blsDeferCalcOriginalValue
```

That has this unfortunate side-effect:

> Because VBA makes and releases a temporary Cell object in the
> preceding code, Visio will process its queue at that point.

My question is, is this also the case with similar code in a .NET VSTO solution, or does it work differently via the .NET interop?

I want to make sure that recalculation is deferred and not triggered until all changes to the diagram are applied in code, so I want to avoid doing anything to trigger recalculation after DeferRecalc is turned on. Thank you for sharing your insights!

Comment: First thought: why the effort at all? I could only think of some very limited cases where you refer to cells that don't exist yet. Second thought: there should be no reason for it to be different. You certainly have tested it already?

Comment: Yacine that is not what Microsoft describes, in this case the cells exist in the shape, but because of the way the code is written temporary cell objects are created and when they are released the diagram is recalculated even with DeferRecalc = True. The question is whether this also happens in .NET solutions, because then we need to be mindful how the code is written otherwise DeferRecalc may not actually defer recalculation (and the potential performance gain may not be realized).

Comment: I haven't played with DeferRecalc for improving the performance. The thing that really helped (I mean REALLY) was writing the formulas in one batch. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Visio.Shape.SetFormulas . With it animated smoothly several hundred shapes - even with a slow python program.

Comment: Because the VSTO add-ins run in-process the performance difference is less but yes GetFormulas/Setformulas/Getresults/Setresults also perform significantly better because your software only goes across the interop once for a bulk set of cell reads/changes.

Comment: In some places DeferRecalc helps even more (but this is observational not performance profiling data, hard to do with the black box that is Visio) but sometimes not, which I am curious whether related to the issue mentioned above.